# Why is the lighting not working properly?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Like the title states, my lighting is somehow not working properly. Even though the debug screen shows that the light level is currently 0, I am somehow still able to see properly.[image]

Comment: This seems to be a bug. Does it go away if you use the "optimise world" feature in the world edit menu and check the "erase cached data" option?

Answer (score 2):

This is because the trapdoors above you block out light, but are considered transparent blocks. Thus, you can still see around you, as it's transparent, but it is light level 0 because it blocks the light source above it, meaning that your hand appears black.

Comment: I don't know why this got so many upvotes. Trapdoors are definitely transparent biocks (server-side) and whether you can see through them depends on the wood type and resource packs.